# How to get the profile name In the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When a user chooses one profile to log in with, I want the name of the profile appear in the url, like this: http://localhost:1234/Bryan

I have this in my Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
             "Home",
             "{username}",
             new { controller = "Home", action = "index", username = "" });
```

Here is my Home-controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string username)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["ProfileId"] != null)
            {


                return View(homeIndexModel);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "ProfileLogin");
        }
```

My question Is: how do I pass the username to the URL from here? I want it to be in the format: http://localhost123/Bryan, not http://localhost123/Home/Index/Bryan

I don't know how to make It appear in the URL.

Comment: You cant have just `http://localhost123/Bryan` - none of your other routes would work.

Comment: And how should my routes look like then?

Comment: Do you want the user name to appear in every url? And how would you want it to be if you had a (say) `/Products/Details/1` url?

Comment: No. I only want it to appear when u are logging in. When u are logging in, u are redirected to the index-method of the home-controller. So everytime you are redirected to the index-method of the home controller, I want the name in the url.

Comment: Then you cold have a specific route, say `url: "Home/{username}"` with `defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"});` so the url would be `http://localhost123/Home/Bryan`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Can u not skip the Home parameter? If u look at facebook. When u are visiting your profile, it just says http://facebook.com/yourusername. I want to do the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112346/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-bryan).